# Timer1 freezes the UI thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, timer, backgroundworker

My programm gets a high-speed data from serialport, and timer reads it , after timer gets value , timer is disabled  and code does sting operations where add  value which accepted earlier from com to listview. THe problem is that UI thread is not completely freezing but it seems laggy when i drag the form also, That code which add +1 every time on the subitem.text - is not smooth.

```
   founditem.SubItems(4).Text = founditem.SubItems(4).Text + 1
```

Why is that as  knows timer creats its own thread, and it shouldnot freeze an UI( i cant get rid of timer, becsouse its neccesary to accept correct data from serial)
Any tips? i tried invoke,begininvoke and background_worker, maybe not correctly.
Also can i call background worker from timer event? I'm not good at asyc tasks. My code is:

```
   Private Sub spOpen()
    Try
        spClose()
        spObj.PortName = "COM4"
        spObj.BaudRate = 230400
        spObj.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
        spObj.DataBits = 8
        spObj.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
        spObj.Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None
        spObj.DtrEnable = False 'imp
        spObj.RtsEnable = False 'imp
        spObj.NewLine = vbCr
        spObj.ReadTimeout = 0
        spObj.WriteTimeout = 250
        spObj.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1
        spObj.Open()

    Catch ex As Exception
        'catch 
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub spClose()
    Try
        If spObj.IsOpen Then
            spObj.Close()
            spObj.Dispose()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'handle the way you want
    End Try
End Sub
Function ReverseString(ByVal sText As String) As String
    Dim lenText As Long, lPos As Long
    If Len(sText) = 0 Then Exit Function
    lenText = Len(sText)
    ReverseString = Space(lenText)

    For lPos = lenText To 1 Step -2
        If lPos > 0 Then Mid(ReverseString, lenText - lPos + 1, 2) = Mid(sText, lPos - 1, 2)
        If lPos = 0 Then Mid(ReverseString, lenText - lPos + 1, 2) = Mid(sText, lPos, 2)
    Next lPos
    'Return


End Function

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'stop the timer (stops this function being called while it is still working
    Timer1.Enabled = False


    ' get any new data and add the the global variable receivedData
    receivedData = ReceiveSerialData()

    'If receivedData contains a "<" and a ">" then we have data
    If ((receivedData.Contains("<") And receivedData.Contains(">"))) Then
        'parseData()
        first_msg = 1

        parseData()
    End If

    ' restart the timer
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
Function  ReceiveSerialData() As String
    Dim Incoming As String
    Try
        Incoming = spObj.ReadExisting()
        If Incoming Is Nothing Then
            Return "nothing" & vbCrLf
        Else
            Return Incoming
        End If
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        Return "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
    End Try
End Function
Function parseData()

    ' uses the global variable receivedData
    Dim pos1 As Integer
    Dim pos2 As Integer
    Dim length As Integer
    Dim newCommand As String
    Dim done As Boolean = False
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    While (Not done)

        pos1 = receivedData.IndexOf("<") + 1
        pos2 = receivedData.IndexOf(">") + 1

        'occasionally we may not get complete data and the end marker will be in front of the start marker
        ' for exampe "55><T0056><"
        ' if pos2 < pos1 then remove the first part of the string from receivedData
        If (pos2 < pos1) Then
            receivedData = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(receivedData, pos2 + 1)
            pos1 = receivedData.IndexOf("<") + 1
            pos2 = receivedData.IndexOf(">") + 1
        End If

        If (pos1 = 0 Or pos2 = 0) Then
            ' we do not have both start and end markers and we are done
            done = True

        Else
            ' we have both start and end markers

            length = pos2 - pos1 + 1
            If (length > 0) Then
                'remove the start and end markers from the command
                newCommand = Mid(receivedData, pos1 + 1, length - 2)

                ' show the command in the text box
                RichTextBox1.Text = ""
                RichTextBox1.AppendText(newCommand & vbCrLf)

                'remove the command from receivedData
                receivedData = Mid(receivedData, pos2 + 1)
                'RichTextBox1.Text &= receivedData


                uart_in = RichTextBox1.Text
                data = ""
                'RichTextBox2.Text = Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, 6, 3)
                'If RichTextBox1.TextLength = 26 Then

                can_id = Mid(uart_in, 6, 3) 'extracting and id
                dlc = Mid(uart_in, 10, 1)
                data = uart_in.Substring(26 - (dlc * 2))
                hex2ascii(data)
                data = data.InsertEveryNthChar(" ", 2)
                '  data = ReverseString(data)
                Dim articlecheck As String = can_id
                Dim founditem As ListViewItem = ListView1.FindItemWithText(articlecheck)
                If Not (founditem Is Nothing) Then
                    founditem.SubItems(0).Text = can_id
                    founditem.SubItems(1).Text = dlc
                    '  If founditem.SubItems(2).Text <> data Then
                    ' founditem.SubItems(2).ForeColor = Color.LightYellow
                    founditem.SubItems(2).Text = data
                    '  End If

                    founditem.SubItems(3).Text = timer_count - founditem.SubItems(3).Text
                    founditem.SubItems(4).Text = founditem.SubItems(4).Text + 1
                    founditem.SubItems(5).Text = asciival
                    ' timer_count = 1
                    first_msg = 0
                Else
                    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(can_id)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dlc)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(data)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(timer_count)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(count)
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(asciival)
                    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)

                End If

            End If ' (length > 0) 

        End If '(pos1 = 0 Or pos2 = 0)

    End While

End Function
Function hex2ascii(ByVal hextext As String) As String
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim value As String
    Dim num As String


    For y = 1 To Len(hextext) Step 2
        num = Mid(hextext, y, 2)
        a = Val("&h" & num)
        If a = 160 Or a = 0 Or a = 9 Or a = 32 Or a = 11 Then a = 46
        value = value & Chr(a)
    Next
    asciival = value

End Function
```

Comment: When you keep adding text to the RichTextBox and never remove anything then after a while that gets *very* expensive.  The RTB has to constantly reallocate its internal buffer and copy existing text into it.  Same basic reason why StringBuilder exists to help with strings.  RTB does not have anything similar, you must therefore ensure you delete old text yourself.

Comment: Thx for replying, i replaced RTB with stringbuilder:     Dim get_buffer As New StringBuilder   get_buffer.Remove(0, get_buffer.Length)
                    get_buffer.Append(newCommand & vbCrLf)
  it imporved performance little bit, but not so much

Comment: Any another ideas, maybe to try use backgroundworker or else?

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim System.Threading.Thread yourthread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf yourfunction())
yourthread.Priority = System.Threading.Priority.Highest
yourthread.Start();
```

you can create a loop in your function and add `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` in the end of the loop to make it work like a timer. You can call all your existing functions through this thread, even the timer.

Be careful while accessing your controls through the thread.

```
Invoke(Sub() yourcontrol.property = someproperty)
```

Comment: You really shouldn't change the thread priority. "Normal priority"-threads are scheduled by the system to give each thread a fair amount of processor time so that all can operate smoothly. Switching priority to high may result in starving other processes instead.

Comment: Afnan sry, i didnt get it

Comment: try changing (AddressOf yourfunction()) to (AddressOf parseData()) 
and run my code, youd understand. parseData is your function, not something else